Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515 || Android studio || window || Flutter || Disk space is 218 GB || installed Media Feature Pack
I got this issue after updating the flutter SDK 34, tried to solve with multiple solutions but still got this error.
My device is window 10
Issue is:-
2024-10-17 11:50:04,786 [ 195174] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:182)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2024-10-17 11:50:04,786 [ 195174] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 30 - Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
2024-10-17 11:50:04,802 [ 195190] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 30 - JDK: 11.0.15; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-10-17 11:50:04,802 [ 195190] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 30 - OS: Windows 10

tried solutions is :-
Installing the Media Feature Pack solved this issue for me. To install it follow these steps:

Type Apps & Features in start search box
Go to apps and features
Go to optional features
Add a feature
Search for "Media Feature Pack"
Install it
Restart your computer

also tried this:-

flutter clean
wipe data
delete emulator and create new one every time
manage the space in my disk, total space is(218 GB)

But didn't get any solutions please suggest some idea how to run the emulator in window.
